# Populating JTable with details from two database tables JDBC

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc, netbeans

I looked at a few videos and questions on here but I can't find what I'm looking for. I'm a programming noob (programming in Java on Netbeans using a Derby database) so be gentle please. I have a database, with 2 tables in it. StudentScores and StudentDetails.

StudentDetails has the columns NAMEID and STUDENTNAME.

StudentScores has the columns NAMEID, SCOREID, DATETAKEN, and SCORE.

I wanna have a JTable in my program, that displays the columns NAME from the first database and DATETAKEN and SCORE from the second table. **How do I do that?** I only found tutorials on how to populate a JTable with all the details from one database table.

I also want the user to be able to view all the records (in the JTable) for a student when their name is selected in a combobox. I know I have to get the ID of the name in the combobox and QUERY that?

I found this 
http://1bestcsharp.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/java-mysql-populate-jtable-Depending-JCombobox-Selected-Value.html

but I got confused because multiple classes were being created. **Do I have to create multiple classes or can I do it all in the same JFrame Form?**

Comment: If your database can perform a join between the two tables (read about joins elsewhere), then your Java program can regard the result of the join as just one table. Would that get you through?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I looked into joins, and inner joined the columns from the two tables that I wanted, is this now a new table? It doesn't show up in the "Tables" section under the database in Services, how do I refer to it in the main program when querying etc.? @OleV.V.

Comment: No it is not a new table. But your code that takes the data from a ResultSet to a TableModel doesn't care how the data in the ResultSet got populated, only that the data is there. So your question is an SQL question not a Swing question.

Comment: okay i've got something working, but it's not showing any data just the column headers. I've also noticed when I view the data in the StudentScores table the NAMEID says <NULL> for every entry and all the records are identical. Do you think that's the problem? How do I fix this? @camickr

Comment: I would think the nameid should have a unique value for every record otherwise how do you uniquely identify each person?

Comment: *"Do I have to create multiple classes or can I do it all in the same JFrame Form?"* That's a design choice you're going to need to make based on how reusable you want the code to be, but I wouldn't start with a `JFrame` as your base class, but start with `JPanel` and add that to an instance of a `JFrame`, it will help make your code more re-usable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class Main extends JFrame {
  private JTable m_simpleTable;

  private SimpleTableModel m_simpleTableModel;

  public Main() {

    m_simpleTableModel = new SimpleTableModel(getData());
    m_simpleTable = new JTable(m_simpleTableModel);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(m_simpleTable);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
  }

  public Vector getData(){
      Vector dummyMacData = new Vector(10, 10);
        dummyMacData.addElement(new Data(new Integer(100), "ABC", "11/12/2016","A+", "E"));
        dummyMacData.addElement(new Data(new Integer(105), "XYZ", "20/01/2015","B-", "E"));
        return dummyMacData;
  }

  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Main m = new Main();

    m.setVisible(true);
    m.setSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
    m.validate();
  }

  class SimpleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    public String[] m_colNames = { "Student Id", "Name", "Date","Score", "" };

    public Class[] m_colTypes = { Integer.class, String.class, String.class, String.class,
        String.class };

    Vector m_macDataVector;

    public SimpleTableModel(Vector macDataVector) {
      super();
      m_macDataVector = macDataVector;
    }
    public int getColumnCount() {
      return m_colNames.length;
    }
    public int getRowCount() {
      return m_macDataVector.size();
    }
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
      Data macData = (Data) (m_macDataVector.elementAt(row));

      switch (col) {
      case 0:
        macData.setStudentId((Integer) value);
        break;
      case 1:
        macData.setName((String) value);
        break;
      case 2:
        macData.setDate((String) value);
        break;
      case 3:
        macData.setScore((String) value);
        break;
      case 4:
        //macData.setE((String) value);
        break;
      }
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
      return m_colNames[col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
      return m_colTypes[col];
    }
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
      Data macData = (Data) (m_macDataVector.elementAt(row));

      switch (col) {
      case 0:
        return macData.getStudentId();
      case 1:
        return macData.getName();
      case 2:
        return macData.getDate();
      case 3:
        return macData.getScore();
      case 4:
        return null;//macData.getE();
      }

      return new String();
    }
  }

}

class Data {
  private Integer studentId;

  private String name;

  private String date;

  private String score;

  private String e;

  public Data() {
  }

  public Data(Integer aa, String bb, String cc, String dd, String ee) {
      studentId = aa;
      name = bb;
      date = cc;
      score = dd;
    e = ee;
  }

public Integer getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}



}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, this goes in the main JFrame right? because all I'm getting is errors for the SimpleTableModel saying it's already defined

Comment: @z33 check for the object which is already created. The error itself having enough informative.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer this link below. Almost the same with your question. Hope this helps.

[How to bring all data of table in JTable and insert it into Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154145/how-to-bring-all-data-of-table-in-jtable-and-insert-it-into-database)

Answer (score 0):

just do this..it should work fine

```
Select 
  sd.NameID,
  sd.StudentsName,
  sm.DATETAKEN,
  sm.Score 
from 
  (firsttablename) sd,
  (secondtablename) sm 
where 
  sd.NameId = sm.NameId 
  and sd.NameID = (nameid you want to display data)
```

but in this you have to make nameid as a foreign key in second table.