# How to bring all data of table in JTable and insert it into Database

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

Hello my friends in this code I want to bring all my data that is entered into `JTable` and insert it into my Database but its wrong in for loop of enter data to database and here is the result:
[http://i67.tinypic.com/5mwgt4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRA1h.png)

```
final void tabledata(){

int rows=jt.getRowCount();
int colms=jt.getColumnCount();
int bpss=0,spss=0;

for(int i=0;i<colms;i++){
for(int j=0;j<rows;j++) {
if(i==0){
    String qtys= jt.getValueAt(j,i).toString();
    int qtyss=Integer.parseInt(qtys);
    System.out.print(qtyss);
    try{stmt.execute("INSERT INTO ITEMS(QTY) VALUES("+qtyss+")");}
    catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
}else{ 
if(i==1){

    String codes= jt.getValueAt(j,i).toString();
    int codess=Integer.parseInt(codes);
    System.out.print(codess);
    try{stmt.execute("INSERT INTO ITEMS(CODE) VALUES("+codess+")");}
    catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    } else{ 
if(i==2){

    String names=jt.getValueAt(j,i).toString();
    System.out.print(names);
    try{stmt.execute("INSERT INTO ITEMS(NAME) VALUES('"+names+"')");}
    catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    } else{ 
if(i==3){

   String bps= jt.getValueAt(j,i).toString();
   bpss=Integer.parseInt(bps);
   System.out.print(bpss);
   try{stmt.execute("INSERT INTO ITEMS(BUYPRICE) VALUES("+bpss+")");}
    catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    } else{ 
if(i==4){

   String sps= jt.getValueAt(j,i).toString();
   spss=Integer.parseInt(sps);
   System.out.print(spss);
   try{stmt.execute("INSERT INTO ITEMS(SELLPRICE) VALUES("+spss+")");}
    catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }}}}}}}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is to download the **rs2xml.jar** after installing this **jar** add it to your library. So you can populate your ResultSet to a TableModel. I made a sample gui using DB Derby where I can insert and populate it to table model. I used a Prepared Statement here.

[image]

```
private void addBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   String inputEmployee = employeeTf.getText();//textfields
   String inputDepartment = departmentTf.getText();//textfields
   
   if(inputEmployee.isEmpty() && inputDepartment.isEmpty()){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up!");
    }//If blank
    else if(inputEmployee.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee Name should not be left blank");//If blank
    }
    else if(inputDepartment.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Department should not be left blank");//If blank
    }
    else{
        String myQuery = "INSERT INTO SAMPLE (EMPLOYEENAME,DEPARTMENT) VALUES (?,?)";
        
        try(Connection myCon = DBUtilities.getConnection(DBType.JDBC);//Establish the connection
        PreparedStatement myPs = myCon.prepareStatement(myQuery);
            ){
            
            myPs.setString(1, employeeTf.getText());
            myPs.setString(2, departmentTf.getText());
            
            myPs.executeUpdate(); // Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE;
            
            System.out.print("Record is inserted");
            
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Table_Employee.getModel();
            model.addRow(new Object[]{employeeTf.getText(),departmentTf.getText()});
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            DBUtilities.processException(ex);
       }
    }//end of else
}
```

[image: Sample]

Syntax creating a table model:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) Table_Employee.getModel();
            //yourTableModelName            //yourTableName
model.addRow(new Object[]{employeeTf.getText(),departmentTf.getText()});
                           //yourTextfield     //yourTextfield
```

Hope this helps. Link for **rs2xml.jar**
http://en.osdn.jp/projects/sfnet_finalangelsanddemons/downloads/rs2xml.jar/

Answer (score 0):

INSERT adds a completely new record into the database.
So, when you INSERT QTY, you create records with just a Quantity, and all other fields are blank.
Then when you INSERT CODE etc, you do the same thing. So new records get created without anything in the other fields.
What I suggest you do is read each row, and then create a single sql statement that says something like :
INSERT INTO ITEMS (QTY, CODE,NAME, BUYPRICE, SELLPRICE) VALUES(..,..,..,..);

This will create records with all fields filled in.